# Can we deploy SSIS with Attunity oracle connection in SQL Server?

Tags: oracle, ssis

I have an SSIS package...which load data from Oracle DB. As it is slow, I started trying Attunity connection ...which need TNS name to get created.

My question is...

1. If I use Attunity connection manager, will it improve the data load speed
2. If I use Attunity connection manager, as it has TNS names used in it...Can we deploy the package in SQL Server ?

Thanks i advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding first question, on one of projects i worked on we experienced better performance with Attunity driver for DB2, maybe You will experience better performance with Attunity to Oracle also. Did You consider Oracle's OLEDB  provider? It is faster than Microsoft's.

Regarding second question, this should give you the answer: everything you need to setup on client (development machine) to run package, you also have to setup on server where you deploy and run that package. This includes installing drivers, setting ODBC connections and so on...

Also, note that BIDS is 32bit application and as such requires 32bit version of connection drivers. If you run the same package in 64bit mode on 64bit hardware then you have to install 64bit driver. If you develop and run packages in 64bit on the same machine, you have to install both 32bit and 64bit drivers. You will maybe need to do some tweaking, but there is a lot of information on the Internet, depending on the database and driver you use.

Comment: I discussed with my DBA team, they are not ready to install the Attunity MSI in server. Is there any other wsy to improve the data load performance ?

Comment: Guess they are not ready to install Oracle's OLEDB driver (from Oracle Client Tools i think) or any other, too? We are using Oracle's provider to transfer data from Oracle to SQL Server and performances are pleasant for us - and better than with Microsoft OLEDB provider for Oracle. I am really sorry but i don't know anything else that could be of any use to You since your dba's won't install additional drivers...

Comment: I just recalled something that might save You time experimenting: SSIS package with source (Oracle's OLEDB provider) and OLEDB destination (Microsoft OLEDB provider for SQL Server) is faster than Execute SQL Task that do INSERT INTO SELECT FROM linked_Server_to_oracle. This means, don't even bother with linked servers, SSIS is way to go. Just find the fastest provider You are allowed to use on server.

Comment: Thanks for all info you provided. I really appreciate your attitude. thanks.